# Make TabbedPage On MasterdetailPage Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem making a tabbed layout on my master detail page. I have tried to do it like this:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailTest.View"
             x:Class="MasterDetailTest.MainPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:Home />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <TabbedPage>
            <TabbedPage.Children>
                <ContentPage Title="Home" Icon="home.png"/>
                <ContentPage Title="Home" Icon="home.png"/>
                <ContentPage Title="Home" Icon="home.png"/>
            </TabbedPage.Children>
        </TabbedPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

But for some reason it's not working adding tabbed page just on xaml, should i've to try this at the cs?

Comment: Inside of your <MasterDetailPage.Detail> you have  <NavigationPage> and  <TabbedPage>. This is not going to work. Please read fundumentals: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/

Comment: so what should do if i want to put a tabbed on masterdetail page?

Comment: read a link I posted, they explain there everything. You cannot put 2 pages inside another page. pick one, either NavigationPage or TabbedPage

Answer (score 2):

you can't put TabbedPage inside NavigationPage. The right order is:
- TabbedPage > NavigationPage > page.

In Fact, you shouldn't mix it. Use MasterDetailPage > NavigationPage
OR TabbedPage > NavigationPage BUT NOT MasterDetailPage > TabbedPage.

this would works for you:

MasterDetail:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/

TabbedPage:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/